# Visually show how the effect of one regressor diminishes the effect and significance of another

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

After fitting my regression models, I found that the effect size and significance of one predictor is greatly diminished once I introduce another, dichotomous variable with a strong effect on the response variable. My interpretation is that the new variable's strong effect "overshadows" the one of the other variable. Based on correlation and VIFs, there don't seem to be any multicollinearity issues.

Assuming my interpretation is correct, how could I visually show how the inclusion of the second variable decreases the effect size and significance of the other variable? I thought about doing a scatter plot, but I think it only shows the strong effect of the new variable, not how the new variable influences the old one. What kind of visualization would be useful here? The goal is not to diagnose anything or to necessarily generate additional insight, but rather to make the regression results more intuitive for the reader of my analysis.

I hope that my question is succinct enough to be answered. I realize that it rests on the assumption that my interpretation of my regression is correct. If you have any other feedback aside from what kind of plot would be the best to do what I want, do share it. Thank you!

These are the regression results.

```
> stargazer(m1,m2,type="text")

==============================================
                      Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                               Y              
                       (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------
X1                   -0.012**       -0.006    
                     (0.005)        (0.005)   
                                              
X2                                 0.750***   
                                    (0.132)   
                                              
Constant             1.438***      1.074***   
                     (0.094)        (0.122)   
                                              
----------------------------------------------
Observations            56            56      
Log Likelihood       -133.332      -116.022   
Akaike Inf. Crit.    270.664        238.044   
==============================================
Note:              *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

This is the plot I made which I am not satisfied with yet.
[image]

Below is the data and code that I am working with.

```
#devtools::install_github("cmartin/ggConvexHull")
library(ggConvexHull)
library(ggplot2)
library(stargazer)
library(car)

# define data
df <- structure(list(Y = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 
                           6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
                           8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
                           3L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L), 
                     X1 = c(-35, -16, -23, -37, -6, -11, -18, -25, -26, -4, -16, 
                            -26, -13, -29, -33, -1, -6, -2, -28, -5, -1, -4, -2, -11, 
                            -38, -13, -16, -3, -1, -2, -10, -6, -12, -8, -9, -1, -4, 
                            -2, -1, -30, -7, -3, -18, -32, -32, -6, -6, -9, -8, -3, -3, 
                            -7, -9, -5, -4, -9), 
                     X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                            0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                            0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                            1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -56L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
                )


# create glms
m1 <- glm(Y ~ X1, data=df, family="poisson")
m2 <- glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data=df, family="poisson")

# there is some correlation
cor(df$X1, df$X2)

# but vifs look okay
vif(m2)

# results show that X1 becomes insignificant when X2 is added
stargazer(m1,m2,type="text")

# plot shows the effect of X2 clearly
# but can it also show the decline in the effect and significance of X1?
p <- ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x=X1, y=Y, color=factor(X2), shape=factor(X2)),
              size=4, alpha=.6, width=0.2, height=0.2) +
  geom_convexhull(aes(x=X1, y=Y, fill=factor(X2)),
                  alpha=.2)
p
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like Simpson's Paradox, so you might want to do a plot actually showing the fitted lines in question much like [plots like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#/media/File:Simpson's_paradox_continuous.svg) that commonly accompany explanations of Simpson's Paradox.

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need want advice on how to visualize data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you, that sounds like it could be it. If I interpret the figure about the Simpson Paradox you linked to correctly, it shows that the estimate of X1 can be very different from that of X1*X2, i.e., one needs to consider the interaction effect of X2 to appropriately interpret X1. Is this interpretation correct? I feel like this is not the same as saying "we hold X2 constant", like in the regression above, without any interaction effect.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for pointing that out. Do you think I could copy-paste this question to Cross Validated and should I delete it here?

Comment: [The Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox) page (where I linked the image) gives a good explanation. You may not have **exactly** Simpson's Paradox (if you can even call it an "exact" sort of thing), but *"the effect size and significance of one predictor is greatly diminished once I introduce another, dichotomous variable with a strong effect on the response variable"* sounds at least similar and I think the visual I shared would be effective: show the model predictions with and without your dichotomous variable on the same plot.

Comment: Yes, that part sounded exactly like my case. In more practical terms, how do I show the model predictions with and without my dichotomous variable? The only step I've managed to go in that direction is using `geom_smooth()` and specifying a simple regression to fit a line, but a multiple regression formula is not supported by `geom_smooth()`. Is there another way to show the model predictions with vs. without the dichotomous variable on the same plot?